# Is it possible to have multiple services or applications share one single config file

Tags: c#, .net, app-config

If I have multiple applications or services which all share one configuration value (e.g. they all access the same database), is there a way to have them share one single config file instead of having to duplicate the values throughout each of their configs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`configSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.sectioninformation.configsource.aspx) attribute to point to a specific file.

Use the same file location from multiple `.config` files.

You can do this with multiple config sections, so one file for connection strings, one for app settings etc...

Answer (score 2):

You could use the [machine.config](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229697%28VS.90%29.aspx) file to define settings shared between all applications on this computer. For ASP.NET applications you could have a web.config file at the root of the file which overrides those machine.config values and have yet another level inside the virtual directory.

Answer (score 0):

You can [load config file programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049868/how-to-load-config-file-programmatically)

[And another link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4738/using-configurationmanager-to-load-config-from-an-arbitrary-location)